# KaliLinux won't boot live from a USB stick

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot, kali-linux, bootable-media

So I installed Kali onto a USB, and it is now registering as 'Kali Live' when I plug it in,(obviously unformatted) but when I go to boot from it, no matter which option I choose, be it live, install, or graphical install, it fails, and produces a loud beeping noise. If I select graphical install, it will let me select my country, and language, but it

```
Can't detect or mount CDROM drives.
```

I have seen a method to fix this, simply by re-inserting the drive, but this does not work for me. I have tried both the

```
dd if=Kali.iso or=Drive
```

method, and the

```
cp Kali.iso /dev/sdX
```

method. However, it refuses to boot, live or otherwise. I have also attempted to open a shell, and use

```
mkdir /cdrom
```

but it throws 'it already exists' back.
I hope someone knows how to fix this, because I really don't want to have to purchase an internet adapter.

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

From your description, there is an issue with your installation media, the downloaded source or compatibility.

The fastest solution would be to redo the process following specific instructions and documenting any errors along the way.   If your system is compatible, there should be no issue.

Install to hard drive with these [instructions](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-hard-disk-install):

Make sure to verify the ISO using  SHA1SUMS following the instructions in [this document](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images).

Make the usb with [these instructions](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install).

After that, if it does not work, document failures you see in the log with f11, but in your place I would not debug something that never worked in the first unless I had very good reason to believe that this was not a software issue or a mix of software and hardware.

Most things like this would work fairly easily on the first try.  When it does not, it's an efficient approach to step back and go methodically.  It shouldn't be a long process, all things considered.

Comment: So it's no longer throwing "Can't detect cd," but now it "Can't copy data from CD." I tried the 32 bit .iso file, and validated it with the SHA1sums, but it won't boot, I have a 64 bit processor, but as far as I'm aware, I can use a x86 architecture anyways. If I'm incorrect. however, then please correct me. I used a blocksize of 4k, just to see if that was an issue, and it was able to detect the USB, but now it still won't boot live, and if I try to do an install, it gives me the "Can't copy data from CDrom."